# Relation between vertically integrated precipitable water and precipitation

Tags: climate-science, meteorology

My background is not in meteorology, but I am interested in climate models of tidally-locked planets of red-dwarf stars. I recently found a great review of different conditions on such planets modeled by 3D GCM models in [Chen et al. 2019](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1907.10048.pdf). Among other things, I was trying to extract information about the precipitation in the substellar point. However, they do not list the precipitation, but only vertically integrated precipitable water in the substellar point (Figure 5c).

I understand that the integrated precipitable water is total mass of the water vapour that could precipitate. Is there a relationship from which it would be possible to deduce the precipitation from the precipitable water? I was tempted to compare the number with the precipitable water on Earth, but then I figured out this could be very misleading, because on Earth there is a [diurnal cycle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diurnal_cycle), which forces the water vapour to precipitate, while on the tidally-locked planet there is not.

Answer about the precipitation in the substellar point from a different source would also be very helpful.

Comment: I mean,  this is very unlikely.  There are some weather things we might be able to tell you,  like we might have a decent guess about the bands if any of wind ... I can already tell you that in the surface winds on average go towards the point of Eternal Noon and thus away from Eternal Midnight, just not sure what sorts of bands may form without a strong Coriolis force. This increases cloud collision at EN which on Earth drives raincloud creation—but what if the temp is too hot for those clouds to exist in the first place? Too hard to answer without a big simulation.

Comment: They ran very detailed simulations in the study, including the cloud formation. They just did not list the precipitation. So I was hoping some relation can be drawn from the precipitable water they list.

Comment: Modelling precipitation is hard enough on Earth, it's going to be highly uncertain for a planet where our observations are extremely limited.